# Javascript php mysql display results in layer while typing

Tags: javascript, php, filtering

I know php & SOL fairly good.  But I don't have any knowledge of JavaScript.  I've been searching Google for an example of filtering names (results), while you type, from a table like the image attached.  Can anyone please direct me to a tutorial that will do this?  Help will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You can use any jQuery plugin for this..[List of jQuery Plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-jquery-live-filter-plugins/)

Comment: Ok many thanks will investigate and give feedback